# WCF Service not save image from Ionic App

Tags: c#, angularjs, wcf, ionic-framework, file-transfer

I'm working on an application and upload images Ionic my WCF Service, the problem is that when the image comes from my WCF code not saved correctly. Save it as an image invalid.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "upload2/{fileName}")]
string Upload2(string fileName, Stream fileStream);

public string Upload2(string fileName, Stream fileStream)
    {

        try
        {
            FileStream fileToupload = new FileStream(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"] + fileName, FileMode.Create);

            byte[] bytearray = new byte[10000];
            int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            } while (bytesRead > 0);

            fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
            fileToupload.Close();
            fileToupload.Dispose();
            return "succ";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message + " - " + ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
```

Code controller AngularJs,

```
$scope.subirFoto = function() {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();

    options.fileKey = "post";

    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;


    var ft = new FileTransfer();

    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://192.68.1.182:8085/IServiceTopStore.svc/upload2/"+options.fileName), win, fail, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it follows if someone needs

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "UploadImage/{fileName}")]
string UploadImage(string fileName);

public string UploadImage(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["post"];
            if (file == null)
                return null;
            string targetFilePath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"] + fileName;
            file.SaveAs(targetFilePath);
            return "succ   " + file.FileName.ToString(); ;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message + " - " + ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
```

Ionic :

```
$scope.subirFoto = function() {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();

    options.fileKey = "post";

    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;


    var ft = new FileTransfer();

    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://192.1.1.1:8085/IServiceTopStore.svc/upload2/"+options.fileName), win, fail, options);
}
```